# package does not exist error?

Tags: java, classpath

```
//Vector.java
package simple;

public class Vector{
public Vector(){
System.out.println("net.mindview.simple.Vector");
}
}


//List.java
package simple;
public class List{
public List() {
System.out.println("net.mindview.simple.List");
}
}

 //LibTest.java
import simple.*;
public class LibTest{
public static void main(String[] args) {
Vector v = new Vector();
List l = new List();
}
}
```

When I try to set the classpath for Vector or List,

like

java classpath "C:\Learning Java\AccessControl" simple.Vector, I could Main method could not be found, please define main method. But in the book I'm using, neither file needs to have a main method.

If I try to run LibTest I get cannot access Vector and class file contains wrong class:Vector, errors.

Comment: Is Vector.java in a folder in the directory called "simple"?

Comment: You seem to be giving conflicting information. Is it "package does not exist" or something about main() method?  Can you produce all and any errors you're getting verbatim?

Comment: Yes @ Rob Watts. And main error is when I try to set classpath, and the package does not exist error is when I try to run LibTest.java @ PM 77-1

Answer (score 1):

From your posted code, nor `Vector` or `List` classes has the `public static void main(String[] args)` method in it, thus you getting the error.

Note that `LibTest` class has it, so it would be better to execute this class:

```
java classpath "C:\Learning Java\AccessControl" other.package.LibTest
```

Comment: @CrewdNBasic what's the package of this `LibTest` class?

Comment: import simple.*; @ Luiggi Mendoza. I feel like all the steps aren't being spelled out to me through the documentation, or I'm doing something basic wrong. I'm using the Thinking in Java book and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html

Comment: @CrewdNBasic do you have a `package XXX` in your `LibTest` class or it just uses `import simple.*`?

Comment: It just uses import.simple.*

Answer (score 0):

To run package first you have to compile it from the directory

ex., C:\package-name\abc.java

package-name: as you mentioned simple.

After it you have to run "abc.java" file from the directory.
ex., C:__*_*_

Hope it will work